# add htaccess file in phpmyadmin in xampp

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, phpmyadmin

How can I add a htaccess file in phpmyadmin in xampp server ?

I have windows 7 operating system.

**I need this to change php.ini values only for phpadmin for example max_execution_time, upload_max_filesize etc.**

Answer (score 0):

When you using the apache2 server

Go to following directory.

**cd /etc/apache2/sites-available**

If you use LS command here you will see following file.

**000-default.conf**

That's the file with default apache configuration which are applied to your sites in /var/www/html folder.

Open this file for editing.

**sudo nano 000-default.conf**

Add following lines after DocumentRoot /var/www/html line.

**Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All


     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all**

Save the file and restart the apache.

**sudo service apache2 restart**

that's it and now your .htaccess file will work